# mySQL where exist or not exist select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay guys I have big problem with mySQL. I need to to do select that gets the free tables in the restaurant in specific time. Here are my tables:

tables:

```
+-------------+
| id  | chairs| 
+-------------+
| 1   | 3     |
| 2   | 5     |
| 4   | 10    | 
| 7   | 12    |
| 10  | 6     |
+-------------+
```

and reservations:

```
+---------------------------------+
| id  | table_id | start_datetime      |
+----------------|---------------------+
| 1   | 3        | 2013-11-27 16:15:00 |
| 2   | 5        | 2013-11-27 19:00:00 |
+----------------|---------------------+
```

I try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_reserveit_tables,wp_reserveit_reservations
WHERE (wp_reserveit_tables.chairs = wp_reserveit_reservations.table_id
       AND wp_reserveit_reservations.start_datetime - INTERVAL 1 HOUR >= '2013-11-29 16:15:00'
       AND wp_reserveit_reservations.start_datetime + INTERVAL 1 HOUR <= '2013-11-29 16:15:00')                                                                                        
OR wp_reserveit_tables.chairs <> wp_reserveit_reservations.table_id
```

but it gives me SQL error.

So please if you have and idea please write it down.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: What are you trying with your two table datum and what's the error it displays.?

Comment: query seems functional, you might want to use nondeprecated join syntax though http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: you have inconsistent column name for start_datetime between your query and your table structure

Comment: why are you joining table.chairs to table_id and not table.id?

Answer (score 0):

Reservation table will have entry only if there are any reservations. So we can do it simply with `NOT IN` clause I guess,

```
SELECT * FROM wp_reserveit_tables WHERE chairs_id NOT IN
(SELECT table_id FROM wp_reserveit_reservations GROUP BY table_id)
```

In your query you have joined them with chairs column with table_id column. So am not sure which one matches. So please alter the column in Where clause as per your requirement.

Comment: Guys I want to thank you especially Mari. Thing that I am trying to make it work for 2 weeks you answer it in 1 hour or less. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

You have column name `start_datetime` in your query and your table structure specifies it to be `starttime`.

Unless you specify further, this does look like a valid error if it is not a typo.